# Running Mongodb Ops manager in docker

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have the dockerfile which correctly installs Mongodb and Ops manager in the container. After that I use an entrypoint.sh to do the setups, at the end of the script I put:

```html
echo "starting mongodb"
service mongod start
echo "starting opsmgr"
service mongodb-mms start
```

When I run the container, from the logs message, the line to start ops manager line is never executed.

How can I do something like: If mongodb is up then execute `service mongodb-mms start`?

Not sure if it is running multiple services in one container beacuse ops manager needs to wait for mongodb to start correctly first.

Answer (score 1):

I found this `Dockerfile` for a very old version of Ops Manager, but the way it waits for the mongodb port to be open still works: https://github.com/deviantony/docker-opsmanager/blob/master/ops-manager/startup.sh

Basically the author uses `nc` to wait until the standard `mongod` port accepts a connection with:

```sh
echo "Waiting for MongoDB"
while true; do
    nc -q 1 database 27017 >/dev/null && break
done
```

Now, make sure when calling Ops Manager that this remains in the foreground, as Docker needs one process to be running.

You can start it with `service start mongodb-mms` and inmediatelly run tail, for instance, like:

```sh
echo "starting mongodb"
service mongod start

# snippet to wait for mongod to be in running state 

echo "starting opsmgr"
service mongodb-mms start

# Keep this startup script busy, if it ends, the Docker container dies.
tail -f /opt/mongodb/mms/logs/mms0.log
```